# How to prevent "any" from being used in TypeScript types and interfaces

Tags: typescript, types, eslint, tsc

I have the `"noImplicitAny": true,` flag in tsconfig.json, and `"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 2,` in place for eslint, but they don't catch things like

```
type BadInterface {
  property: any
}
```

Are there any configuration options through tsconfig, or eslint to flag this? Our team's contractors use `any` for lots of properties in interfaces, and I can't seem to find a way to prevent this from passing `tsc` or `eslint` commands in the CI workflow.

To just be completely clear, I want something to let me know when someone uses type `any` for a key on an interface or type. It seems to be fine when TS is inferring the type from an `any`, but I want it blow up when someone tries to use `any` as a type anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use the `ban-types` rule to prevent explicit use of `any`.

For example:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/ban-types": [
  2,
  {
    "types": {
      "any": "Don't use 'any' because it is unsafe",
    },
    "extendDefaults": true,
  }
}
```

[Docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md)